# titlesec and indentation

Tags: formatting, titlesec, section-titles

I'm using the `titlesec` package to format the sections of my article. Basically, I wish the section number aligned with the left margin of the main text and the section title aligned with the first line of an indented paragraph, like this:

```
1.    Section title
      text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
```

I tried some solutions like the following one but with no luck. Thank you for the help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{\the\parindent}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do that is to place the section number of a fixed length, the same as that used to define `\parindent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thesection.}}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I used `1cm` instead of `2em` to set `\parindent`, because `2em` will not have the same length in the section title than in the paragraph, since the section title is in bold font. The use of `\titlespacing` is only to automatically indent the paragraph right after the section title, the lengths used are the default ones, taken in `titlesec`'s [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

Comment: Thank you, Mr Vincent, it worked perfectly. I have another question: how can I add a regular space after the section number instead of an indentation?

Comment: @TylerD007 you can change ``1cm`` to another length if you prefer. If you really just want a regular space after the section number, you can place only ``\thesection. `` (with the space after the dot) in the third argument of ``\titleformat``.